# Calculating total based on selected items from Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to calculate the total after a user selects which flavor pizza and how many they would want. The user can only order one style of pizza currently. the prices will range from $7-$10. Since I'm populating the selection list with the JS array, I don't know how to add an id to each option. I know if I could add an id to each array item, I'd be able to easily calculate the total but for some reason I can't figure this out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <form>
      <h2>Customer Information</h2>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="name" class="col-form-label">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="First and Last Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="phone" class="col-form-label">Phone Number</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="123-456-7890">
        </div>
      </div>
      <h2>Delivery Address</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Address" class="col-form-label">Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Address" placeholder="1234 Main St">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Address2" class="col-form-label">Address 2</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Address2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="City" class="col-form-label">City</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="City" placeholder="Springfield">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="State" class="col-form-label">State</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="State" placeholder="MO">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          <label for="inputZip" class="col-form-label">Zip</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip" placeholder="65806">
        </div>
      </div>
      <h2>Order Details</h2>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="pizzaChoice" class="col-form-label">Choose a Pizza Type</label>
          <select id="pizzaChoice"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="orderAmount" class="col-form-label">How Hungry Are You?</label>
          <select id="orderAmount"></select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Place Order</button>
    </form>
  </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      var order = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'];
      select = document.getElementById('orderAmount');
      for(quant in order) {
        select.add(new Option(order[quant]));
      };
      var pizzaTypes = ['Cheese', 'Pepperoni', 'Veggie', 'Hawaiian', 'Supreme'],
      select = document.getElementById('pizzaChoice');
      for(pizzas in pizzaTypes) {
        select.add(new Option(pizzaTypes[pizzas]));
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First off, you've got an undefined variable error in there. `items` variable is not defined (line 74).

Comment: oops. that was something I was working to change. I've edited the code to show what I had working.

Comment: Look up documentation for new Option - you'll see that there's a property that allows you to define a value that isn't displayed to the user.  You can use that value in your calculations.  If you *really* want to add an ID, I'm pretty sure the "Option" object can be treated like any HTML tag and you can use the attributes array.

Comment: You can add an id like this: `var newOption = new Option(pizzaTypes[pizzas]); newOption.id = "someUniqueId"; select.add(newOption);` but again, will this make easier the price calculation?

Comment: instead of using ids, set a value for every option, say:  `select.add(new Option(pizzaTypes[pizzas], pizzas));`, this will generate  <option value="0">Cheese</option>, <option value="1">Pepperoni</option> and so on. Then you will know that `pizzaChoice` will be 0 for Cheese, 1 for Pepperoni and so on. By the way, you must add attribute *name* to your select fields.

Comment: so in the HTML I'd have it formatted like this?  <select> <option value="0">Cheese</option></select>